# Training a CNN to convert ellipses into circles

Tags: keras, cnn, image-recognition

My current project has to do with modeling the effects of blurring/convolution of objects in various imaging processes. Right now, I am starting off with a preliminary, artificial model. I am using Keras to accomplish this.

I create artificial ideal data as a set of circles in random locations in a 128 x 128 image. I then have a routine that takes the coordinates and sizes of these circles as input and replaces the circles with ellipses at the same locations.

I am trying to train a convolutional neural network to perform the inverse of this function, i.e. read the images with ellipses as input and replace them with circles. I create training pairs by grouping these two image types together with the images with ellipses as inputs and the images with circles as outputs.

How can I design a neural network which accomplishes this? Right now, the one that I am using merely returns distorted copies of the images of ellipses instead of outputting images with circles.

I have played around with multiple different CNN structures, as you can see in the commented-out code:

```
model = Sequential()

#model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (80, 128, 128, )))
model.add(Conv2D(nb_classes, kernel_size=3, padding = 'same',
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=(128,128,1)))
#model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size = 3, activation='relu', padding = 'same'))
#model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same'))
#model.add(Dropout(0.25))
#model.add(Flatten())
#model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
#model.add(Dropout(0.5))
#model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))

#model.add(UpSampling2D((4,4)))

model.add(Conv2D(nb_classes, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding='same'))
#model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (128, 128,)))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

Comment: You should rather use classical methods to transform the ellipses. I my opinion it makes no sense to do something like this with neural networks. But it is an interesting task if you want to play around with neural networks.

Answer (score 1):

Use your generated images to train an encoder-decoder that attempts to rebuild the input image. We'll call these pieces the input encoder and ellipse decoder. In parallel, train a second decoder that takes the input encoder (i.e. embedding representation) as input and attempts to rebuild the original circle image. The input encoder + circle decoder can then be used together for scoring out-of-sample observations.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to learn what encoders and decoders are and then implement this as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The principle of your model would be analogous to the one of a **Denoising Autoencoder**. In this kind of Autoencoders, you train a Network to reconstruct an image from a deteriorated version of it.

You need something similar to that: training a convolutional Autoencoder to "get a circle out of an input ellipse".

You can take a look at [this implementation](https://keras.io/examples/mnist_denoising_autoencoder/) of a Denoising Autoencoder on the Keras website. I think that's a good start.